# How to display output from expect?

Tags: expect

I'm trying to read data from a machine that uses a telnet style interface using `expect`.  An interactive telnet session works like this:

```sh
% telnet 10.92.177.14 53595
Trying 10.92.177.14...
Connected to 10.92.177.14.
Escape character is '^]'.
NOKEY
power_status ?
"on"
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
```

I sent the command `power_status ?` and get the response `"on"`.

I tried the following expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn telnet 10.92.177.14 53595
expect -- "NOKEY\r"
send "power_status ?\r"
interact
```

It returns this output and remains open:

```
spawn telnet 10.92.177.14 53595
Trying 10.92.177.14...
Connected to 10.92.177.14.
Escape character is '^]'.
NOKEY
power_status ?
"on"
```

How can suppress everything but the `"on`" output, and make it exit afterward?  If I remove the `interact` line then it does exit but I don't see the response.

Comment: Is telnet a must? What if you just do `echo 'power_status ?' | nc 10.92.177.14 53595`? Do you get `"on"` in response?

Comment: That command just returns `NOKEY`.  I'd be happy to use netcat instead but I need to figure out how to use it with expect.